# h1 icon vertical-align not work in bootstrap 2.3.2

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I have this `css/HTML` code for show icon in h1 :

CSS:

```
h1 {
font-size:32px;
font-weight:400;
margin:6px 0;

}
h1>i {
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
text-align:center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<h1><i class="icon-search"></i>Bootstrap 3 Glyphicons</h1>
</div>
```

But vertical-align not worked for bootstrap 2.3.2. `NOTE: I know this worked in version 3.+`. how to fix this problem for this version?

[demo here](http://bootply.com/86086)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead to overload twitter bootstrap default rule for `h1` :

```
h1>[class^="icon-"], h1>[class*=" icon-"] {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[Updated demo](http://bootply.com/86092)**

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be more css to it than showing in the bootply css-text-field.

```
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
    vertical-align:text-top;
}
```

If you add

```
.icon-search {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

...to your css, it will position the image centered vertically.

Comment: although it works, this will match every `.icon-search` in the page, and only `.icon-search`. No other icon. I think that the OP wants to match every icon inside `h1` tag (he is trying : `h1>i`)

Comment: Good thinking, you're right. But the moral of the story here is: use firebug to see which statements are being overridden.